# Why there are not texture features like Haralick or Zernike in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-extraction

I desperately need texture features for my OpenCV-based image recognition app (**EDIT: written in C++/Qt**).

When I read academic papers on CV in biology, the most describe *Haralick Texture Features* and *Zernike Moments* as standard for texture classification. Why are they missing in OpenCV?

Are they are not up to date? Which alternatives are there in OpenCV than?

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @GPPK Oh, thanks! It's C++. Probably using python I wouldn't face the problem, as python certainly provides one or another package for this. For C++ I've found either some old C-code from 1999 or some not easy to integrate libraries with many dependencies (boost, etc.)

Comment: "Which alternatives are there in OpenCV" - Gabor, lbph. (even tried[Zernike](https://github.com/berak/uniform-lbp/blob/3.0_old/Zernike.cpp) once, but found it slow and unaccurate)